# selecting by "second level" key on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

let's say I have an structure like that in mongodb:

```
{
  'source1': {
                'name':'john',
                'phone':'5555555'
             }

  'source2': {
                'name':'john',
                'city':'new york'
             }

  'source3': {
                'name':'john',
                'phone':'5555555'
                'city':'new york'
             }
}
```

how can I select all sources that have the 'phone' fields (source1 and source3)?
something like *.phone {$exists:true}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can't do it like you said "*.phone" in mongodb you should always specify field on what you try to do querying.

So one ugly solution can be manually check it in each source:

```
db.sources.find( { $or : [ { "source1.phone" : { $exists : true },
                           { "source2.phone" : { $exists : true },
                           { "source3.phone" : { $exists : true }]} };
```

But if you redesign your schema to be with one nested array of sources:

```
{
  'sources': [{
                'name':'john',
                'phone':'5555555',
                'source_name': "source1"
             },
             {
                'name':'john',
                'city':'new york',
                'source_name': "source2"
             }]
}
```

You can do it much more easier, following request return all sources that contains phone field:

```
db.sources.find({ "sources.phone" : { $exists : true })
```

Comment: thanks!is it possible to do the same kind of search if I just declare it as an array [{'name':'john', ...], without the 'sources' label?

Comment: @Lem0n: Can you post document structure you talking about?

Comment: it's exactly the same as the one you posted, but starting after 'sources': ... so, just an array [{}, {}] instead of {'sources':[{}, {}]}

Comment: @Lem0n: without label it will be invalid json. Or you mean one document for one source?

Comment: hm, I got to, for instance, dbs.a.insert([10]), so I thought it would be possible to do a search similar to the one I said before in this case. I guess it isn't then. Thanks